# C# NAudio music is out of sync with the lyrics

Tags: c#, naudio

I am making a karaoke-like app with C# and NAudio.

```
while(!_stopSync)
{
    int currentMs = musicPlayer.GetCurrentTimeMS(); // Retrieve the current millisecond value from WaveOut
    bool jumped = musicPlayer.GetIsJumped();
    int finalOffset = lastoffset;
    
    if (previousMs != currentMs || jumped)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedOffsets.Count; i++)
        {
            var value = sortedOffsets[i];
            if (value > currentMs)
            {
                break;
            }
            finalOffset = value; // Assign the current value
            finalIndex = i; // Assign the current index
        }
    }
    
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
    {
        UpdateUI(finalIndex, currentMs);
    }));
    
    lastoffset = finalOffset;
    previousMs = currentMs; 
}
```

I am using this code to sync the music with the lyrics. `sortedOffsets` variable is a `Dictionary<int, int>` where the Key is an offset of the lyric in milliseconds, and the value is an index of a UIElement that has the lyric text that is not relevant to this issue.

This implementation works normally if the user doesn't change the current time. But whenever the user jumps to any second or millisecond the sound and lyrics go out of sync. This issue is becoming more noticeable if the jumped time is closer to the end of the music because the latency gap increases.

And here is the part of the Music Player class implementation.

```
private WaveOutEvent waveOut;
private AudioFileReader audioFileReader;

public void JumpToSecond(double second)
{
    if (waveOut != null && audioFileReader != null)
    {
        audioFileReader.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second);
        Jumped = true;
    }        
}

public void JumpToMs(int offset)
{
    JumpToSecond(offset / 1000);
}

public int GetCurrentTimeMS()
{
    if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
        return 0;
    return (int)(audioFileReader.CurrentTime.TotalMilliseconds);
}

public bool GetIsJumped()
{
    bool isJumped = Jumped;
    Jumped = false;
    return isJumped;
}

// Other init, play, pause, volume stuff
```

What causes this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `offset / 1000.0` to avoid truncation due to integer division.  By making one of the operands a double, you get floating point division without loss of accuracy.

Comment: Thank you. I did that but the issue still persists.